# Como acessar, dentro de uma função, uma variável global que tem o mesmo identificador que a variável dentro da função?

Tags: javascript, funções, scope

Vamos supor que eu tenha o seguinte código em JavaScript:

```js
let variavel = 22
function funcao(){
  let variavel = 333
  console.log(variavel)
}
funcao() //333
```

Percebemos que, como a variável declarada dentro da função (local) tem o identificador igual ao da variável global (declarada fora da função), a que tem prioridade é a local.

No entanto, gostaria de acessar a global dentro da função, se possível. Como fazer? Nesse caso, gostaria de imprimir 22 em vez de 333.

Sei que, no navegador, variáveis ***var*** são anexadas ao objeto *window*, mas aqui não se trata de uma variável ***var***, também não queria depender do objeto *window*, visto que queria pode fazer o mesmo no node, por exemplo.

Comment: Não pode enviar a variável como parâmetro da função e alterar seu nome? Por exemplo, vc chama a função com `funcao(variavel)` e recebe com outro nome: `function funcao(novavariavel){}`... o valor de `variavel` fora da função fica agora dentro da função com o nome `novavariavel`.

Comment: Sim, eu poderia fazer isso.. mas gostaria de saber no caso específico mostrado no código msm. Se é possível fazer isso etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Utilizando o mesmo identificador não é possível, pois você bloqueia (*shadow*) o acesso à variável global ao declarar um identificador igual dentro da função. A única saída nesse caso é declarar a global com `var` e acessar diretamente pelo objeto global (`window` ou `global`), como você mesmo citou.

Porém eu pensaria duas vezes antes de descartar a [sugestão do Sam](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/432294/como-acessar-dentro-de-uma-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-uma-vari%c3%a1vel-global-que-tem-o-mesmo-identifi#comment836841_432294). Não costuma ser boa ideia que uma função dependa de variáveis globais, isso torna o código mais difícil de entender e manter. Sempre que puder, prefira passar valores como argumento.